# Evaluate Limit only if both directions(sides) are equal? E.g. $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\text{DNE}$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want the limit of a function to only evaluate if both the left and right hand side are equal. For example $\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ doesn't exist(two sided limit). However, the right side is $\lim _{x\to 0+}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\infty $ and the left side is $\lim _{x\to 0-}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=-\infty $. 
I want to create it, so:`Limit[1/x, x -> 0]` gives me **does not exist**, instead of $\infty$ which is **only the right side limit**!

[image]

How can I archive this?

[image]

This is what the graph looks like:

[image]

PS: I am **new to *Mathematica*** and **tried to find it in the documentations**, however, all I found was I can specify `Direction ->` to `1` or `-1`, but there was no `0` for it checking both sides and returning a value **only if both sides are equal.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Limit` can actually approach a value from any direction in the complex plane. For instance `Limit[__, Direction -> I]` is valid.

To have a bidirectional limit along the real line, you'll have to implement it yourself. Something like this should work pretty well I think.

Basically just take limits in both directions and make sure they equal.

```
$NonNumericPattern = ComplexInfinity | _DirectedInfinity | _Interval | 
  Undefined | Indeterminate;

equalQ[l : $NonNumericPattern, r_, ___] := l == r
equalQ[l_, r : $NonNumericPattern, ___] := l == r
equalQ[l_, r_, assum_: True] := PossibleZeroQ[l - r, Assumptions -> assum]

Options[RealLimit] = FilterRules[Options[Limit], Except[Direction]];

RealLimit[expr_, x_ -> a_, ops : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Block[{llim, rlim},

    llim = Limit[expr, x -> a, ops, Direction -> 1];
    rlim = Limit[expr, x -> a, ops, Direction -> -1];

    ConditionalExpression[rlim, equalQ[llim, rlim, OptionValue[Assumptions]]]
  ]

RealLimit[1/x, x -> 0]
```

> ```
> Undefined
> ```

### Edit

Since version 11.2, `Limit` is bidirectional over the reals by default:

```
$VersionNumber
```

> ```
> 11.2
> ```

```
Limit[1/x, x -> 0]
```

> ```
> Indeterminate
> ```

Comment: Cool, I am new to mathematica + calculus and this is really helpful. I really appreciate taking the time to write all this code to fit my needs exactly. I am very grateful, thanks a lot!!! I still have to learn how to write my own functions like this in mathematica, but thanks for the help.

Comment: Is there anyway to append this into a built in function within my version of mathematica or make it so when I create a new notebook that it automatically runs the code to define "RealLimit"?

Comment: @JamesSmith Yes, though it's a bit of a hack. First in Mma, run `FileNameJoin[{$BaseDirectory, "Kernel", "init.m"}]`. Locate this file on your machine and open it. Next, paste ``Notation`AutoLoadNotationPalette = False;
Needs["Notation`"];
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{"Limit", "[", "args_", "]"}]]\[DoubleLongRightArrow]ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{"RealLimit", "[", "args_", "]"}]]]``, paste the code for `RealLimit`, and save the file. Now quit Mma and reopen. Now every time you type `Limit[...]`, Mathematica will parse it as `RealLimit[...]`. Let me know if you have any troubles.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again. You are the best.